# Internal and Infrastructure directories in project

Tags: .net, github, project

I've noticed that several projects have a "Internal" directory in the code base. Example:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal
- https://github.com/aspnet/Core/tree/master/src/Castle.Core/Core/Internal
- https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/Internal

At first one may be lead to believe that these directories stores classes declared with the `internal` access modifier but looking in the directories you see that the classes residing inside are actually declared with the `public` access modifier.

Is the presence of a "Internal" directory a common occurrence or established practice in the .NET world, and what is it for? What goes there? What belongs there?

I've also noticed a directory called "Infrastructure" in several projects:

- https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Infrastructure
- https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Server/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server/Infrastructure
- https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/Infrastructure

Likewise I would like to ask if this is a common occurrence or established practice and what this directory is for and what belongs in there?

Answer (score 0):

For my mind, the better way is create separate project called "Infrastructure" and move to this project all interfaces, public abstract classes and other contracts.
Then referenced this project from all projects, that should know about this contracts.

It's not common way, but i often see it.

Comment: This was not what I had in mind, but nonetheless it has very interesting. However this question was more if this was just a library that I distribute, not a internal component shared among projects in a solution.

Comment: In this case i prefer put interfaces and implementation in one folder and mark necessary classes as internal.

For my mind, namespaces shoud not reflect my prefer folder structure (such as separate internal and public classes).
And in my projects i i think, that class Repository shoud located in folder "Repositories". It's simple and clear project organization.

Especially if it is public library and other people woud use it.